# Node Access permission for anonymous users

Tags: 7, users

The website is set Only login users can access. but There are times a node maybe allow an anonymous user to access by sending the user the URL for the node.

I try to use the Content_Access module to make it but it failed to make it.

How can achieve it??

Answer (score 2):

Content Access controls access by content type. The module you want is the [Nodeaccess](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess) module.

Comment: Content Access also has per-node permissions, you just have to check the box to allow it on the content type.

Comment: Yeah @Cthos you are right，but

Comment: Yeah @Cthos you are right，but you didn't follow me well.In order to permit the login in use to access the web only,I set nothing permissions to anonymous users,but sometimes there are requirements for the anonymous users to visit some node through the url i provide. So i use the content_access to make fortune,to set access permission for anonymous user to access the specific node ,but i didn't work. i guess maybe the content_access module cannot overwrite the permission from the drupal core.

Comment: @user12758 - No, I'm about 74% certain it can. Did you rebuild content permissions after you did that? It could well be caching the permissions.

Comment: @Cthos - No it can't.

Comment: Access control modules do not grant access, they remove it. If you have not given the anonymous user 'View published content' permission in core, the other modules will not grant that access. To restrict access, you first give the access to the visitors in core, then you restrict their access on a per node or per content type basis. Then the only nodes they will see are the one where you permit access. You cannot set up a site with no permissions to the anonymous user.

Comment: @Triskelion - The remaining 26% concedes that point.

Comment: @Triskelion I guess you are right!

Comment: Do you have it working now?

Comment: @Triskelion Yes.I use the content_access Module for node_level permission set. And let the anonymous users have the permission to view published contents. For every node published i could uncheck the view permission for anonymous users except for the ones that i want the anonymous user to view.